# Google Analytics in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have implemented Google Analytics in my android app where I can see number of new users and active users detail there. I uploaded the app on Google Play Store.

When I see number of downloads on Google Play Store there it is displaying around 20k and Google Analytics for my same android app is displaying more than 40k new users.

What it is wrong with this analytics ? Doesn't Google Analytics work perfect for android apps ?

I am tracking each screens of my application like below.

First Activity in `onResume()`

```
EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Screen 1");
tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

Second Activity in `onResume()`

```
EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Screen 2");
tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upgrade to GA 4.+?

Comment: @Joseph No I can't right now. Doesn't old sdk work correctly ?